# GKE - Bypass Pod LoadBalancer (Pod's external IP) to Pod's container's IP at runtime for WebSocket purpose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, websocket, kubernetes-pod

I have the following situation:

I have a couple of microservices, only 2 are relevant right now.
- Web Socket Service API
- Dispatcher Service

We have 3 users that we'll call respectively 1, 2, and 3. These users connect themselves to the web socket endpoint of our backend. Our microservices are running on Kubernetes and each services can be replicated multiple times inside Pods. For this situation, we have 1 running container for the dispatcher, and 3 running containers for the web socket api. Each pod has its Load Balancer and this will be each time the entry point.

In our situation, we will then have the following "schema":

[image]

---

Now that we have a representation of our system (and a legend), our 3 users will want to use the app and connect.

[image]

As we can see, the load balancer of our pod forwarded the web socket connection of our users across the different containers. Each container, once it gets a new connection, will let to know the Dispatcher Service, and this one will save it in its own database.

Now, 3 users are connected to 2 different containers and the Dispatcher service knows it.

---

The user 1 wants to message user 2. The container A will then get a message and tell the Dispatcher Service: `Please, send this to the user 2`.

As the dispatcher knows to which container the user 2 is connected, I would like to send a request directly to my Container instead of sending it to the Pod. Sending it to the Pod is resulting in sending a request to a load balancer which actually dispatches the request to the most available container instance...

[image]

How could I manage to get the container IP? Can it be accessed by another container from another Pod?

**To me, the best approach would be that, once the app start, it gets the current container's IP and then send it within the register request to the dispatcher, so the dispatcher would know that ContainerID=IP**

Thanks!

## edit 1

There is my `web-socket-service-api.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-socket-service-api
spec:
  ports:
    # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: grpc
    # Port that accepts gRPC and JSON/HTTP2 requests over HTTP.
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: rest
    # Port that accepts WebSockets.
    - port: 8082
      targetPort: 8082
      protocol: TCP
      name: websocket
  selector:
    app: web-socket-service-api
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-socket-service-api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-socket-service-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: web-socket-service-api
          image: gcr.io/[PROJECT]/web-socket-service-api:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8081
            - containerPort: 8082
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dispatcher ≈ Message broker

As how I understand your design, your *Dispatcher* is essentially a message broker for the pods of your *Websocket Service*. Let all Websocket pods connect to the broker and let the broker route messages. This is a *stateful* service and you should use a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for this in Kubernetes. Depending on your requirements, a possible solution could be to use a MQTT-broker for this, e.g. [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/). Most MQTT brokers have support for websockets.

### Scale out: Multiple replicas of pods

> each services can be replicated multiple times inside Pods. For this situation, we have 1 running container for the dispatcher, and 3 running containers for the web socket api.

This is not how Kubernetes is intented to be used. Use multiple **replicas of pods** instead of multiple containers in the pod. I recommend that you create a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for your *Websocket Service* with as many replicas you want.

### Service as Load balancer

> Each pod has its Load Balancer and this will be each time the entry point.

In Kubernetes you should create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that load balance traffic to a set of pods.

**Your solution**

> To me, the best approach would be that, once the app start, it gets the current container's IP and then send it within the register request to the dispatcher, so the dispatcher would know that ContainerID=IP

Yes, I mostly agree. That is similar to what I have described here. But I would let the *Websocket Service* establish a connection to the *Broker/Dispatcher*.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, sorry for my "miss-wordings".. I have multiple pods, I miss used the words container/pods here...I am still very new to this as it is my first project over GCP and Kubernetes/Docker. I didn't think about it but I just added the `config.yaml` so you can get more information. I hesitated to use `pub/sub` between my WSS and my DS, however, it means I would have to have one queue per WSS and if one of them crash, then I don't know how would I be able to handle the current messages that are still in the given queue.

Comment: For the DS, in this situation, it is just redirecting messages incoming from the WSS but in my project, the DS gets requested by the `others` and so the users almost don't use the web socket to send data, but only to receive. The issue would be the same if the Sockets were connected to the DS instead of the WSS: "How can I reached the user if I pass by the load balancer? Even using a queue, how can I point a given Pod? The DS also communicate with my Push Notification Service in my current project, so I need it to act that way right now"

Comment: Not one queue per WSS, you should use one queue per **user** - so the queue is like a mailbox for the user. When sending a message to the user, publish a message on the queue to the user. When the user connects it start to listen to his messages, and receive all messages it have not read earlier. This can also be solved with Kafka.

Comment: Idependent of how request are load balanced, when a WSS receive a request for a user, they look in the mailbox for that **user**.

Comment: Hey @Jonas, can you please update your answer with the code I provided as response at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097215/how-can-i-get-pod-external-ip-from-go-code-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

Any pod, has some information about itself. And one of the info, is it own IP address. As an example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_POD_IP;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
```

Within the container, MY_POD_IP would contain the IP address of the pod. You can let the dispatcher know about it.

```
$ kubectl logs envars-fieldref
10.52.0.3


$ kubectl get po -owide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
envars-fieldref                  1/1     Running   0          31s   10.52.0.3    gke-klusta-lemmy-3ce02acd-djhm   <none>           <none>
```

Note that it is not a good idea to rely on pod IP address. But this should do the trick.

Also, it is exactly the same thing to send a request to the pod or to the container.